# Be more flexible with the input for Merge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, merged-questions, moderator-tools

When you want to merge two questions, the form requires you enter the post number, and only the post number, in order to identify the target post to merge with.

This is a pain in the butt.  Please don't make us do this.

Please, at a minimum, accept a full URL as the value for the target post.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with the next build we'll parse URLs (for lookups too) in both the modal and the `/merge-questions` page as well.

Comment: Btw, what does that lookup link do?  I tried using it one time and it just sat there, spinning.

Comment: @Will - it'll look up the question and give a quick summary so you can confirm you got the right one

Comment: BTW, don't forget about merging users as well!

Comment: @Will - absolutely, it's on my todo in the next few days.

Comment: @Will - in the next build we'll support URLs for users (and a bit faster/linkable lookup) on the merge option - edit: now complete

Comment: Just merged a user and found that it didn't like the full URL of the master user so came here to add a comment, but I see I've been beaten to it.